# Method Won't Update GUI After Scanner is Called

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jframe

Why wont the screen update with the new panel ( called by `theView.continueToGame()` ) if `cont()` is called? It seems to work if I comment out where `ask()` calls `cont()`. Could someone please explain why this is happening? It appears that something with the loop is messing it up.

Driver.java

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller con = new Controller();
        con.ask();
    }

}
```

Controller.java

```
public class Controller {

    private View theView = new View();
    private Model theModel = new Model();

    public void ask()
    {
        theView.displayMenu();

        cont();

        System.out.println("ready");

        theView.continueToGame();


    }

    private void cont()
    {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = 0;

        while(!(input == 1))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue");
            input = 0;
            try 
            {
                input = stdin.nextInt();
            } 
            catch (InputMismatchException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("error");
                stdin.next();
            }

        }

        stdin.close();
    }
}
```

View.java

```
public class View extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Serial id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String String1 = "1";
    private String String2 = "2";

    View()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void displayMenu()
    {
        this.add(new startMenu());
    }

    public void continueToGame()
    {
        this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        this.add(new gameScreen());
    }

    class startMenu extends JPanel{

        /**
         * Serial id
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private startMenu()
        {
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            setBackground(Color.blue);

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(String1, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
        }

    }

    class gameScreen extends JPanel
    {

        /**
         * Serial id
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private gameScreen()
        {
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            setBackground(Color.green);

            g.setColor(Color.black);

            g.drawString(String2, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
        }

    }



}
```

edit:

changing `cont()` to

```
private void cont()
{
    Integer input = -1;

    while(!(input == 0))
    {

        input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(theView, "Continue?", null, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
        System.out.println(input);
    }


}
```

doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a threading issue, where a blocking method is blocking your GUI's event thread freezing your program. This is coming about because you're trying to combine a console program, with its linear program logic with an event-driven GUI program.

The solution is simple: don't do this. Get rid of your `new Scanner(System.in)` and only get user input only in an event-driven way through your GUI. You could use a JOptionPane or a JDialog to get this input, either would work great, but just not the `new Scanner(System.in)`. Myself, I'd simply use a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)`.

As a side note, you are using class names, like View and Controller, as if you plan to do a Model-View-Control type of program design which is a ***GREAT*** idea if you ask me, but the Control should handle the GUI's user input, not the console's.

---

**Edit**
I was wrong -- your problem is that you aren't calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on your container after swapping components. i.e.,

```
public void continueToGame()  {
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    this.add(new gameScreen());
    revalidate(); // tells layout managers to layout new components
    repaint();  // redraw everything
}
```

Better not to worry about these things and use a CardLayout to swap your view JPanels.

---

**Edit 2**
CardLayout is actually pretty easy to use, but if you add it to a JFrame, you're actually adding it to the contentPane, and must use the contentPane when calling the `show` method of your CardLayout object. For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Controller con = new Controller();
      con.ask();
   }
}

class Controller {

   private View theView = new View();
   private Model theModel = new Model();

   public void ask() {
      theView.displayMenu();

      if (cont(theView)) {
         System.out.println("ready");
         theView.setView(View.GAME);
      }
   }

   private boolean cont(View theView) {
      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(theView, "Go on to game?");
      return result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
   }
}

class View extends JFrame {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   public static final String START = "start";
   public static final String GAME = "game";
   private String String1 = "1";
   private String String2 = "2";
   private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

   View() {
      // setVisible(true); // don't call this til all added to gui
      setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
      // setSize(400, 400); 
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      getContentPane().setLayout(cardLayout);
      add(new StartMenu(), START);
      add(new GameScreen(), GAME);

      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public void displayMenu() {
      this.add(new StartMenu());
   }

   public void setView(String constant) {
      cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), constant);
   }

   // class names should begin with an upper case letter
   class StartMenu extends JPanel {
      private static final int PREF_W = 400;
      private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private StartMenu() {
         setVisible(true);
      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         setBackground(Color.blue);

         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawString(String1, this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
      }

   }

   // class names should begin with an upper case letter
   class GameScreen extends JPanel {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private GameScreen() {
         setVisible(true);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         setBackground(Color.green);
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.drawString(String2, this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
      }

   }
}

class Model {

}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I only made that as a skeleton to test the GUI's updating method, but now I can see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Strategos: my advice is correct, but my explanation for your error is wrong. Please see edit.

Comment: Ok thanks for the assistance. Adding those methods seems to fix the problem. So that means that it should work even with console input. I've never used CardLayout; guess i'll check it out.